# Why I can´t set the classpath in a jar file, which was build by maven assembly plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I used the maven assembly plugin to create a executable jar file. But theres is a way to set the current classpath into the manifest file of this jar file.

Here is the pom.xml declaration:

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>
                        jar-with-dependencies
                    </descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    <manifestEntries>                           
                        <Project-Build-SourceEncoding>UTF-8</Project-Build-SourceEncoding>                          
                        <Class-Path>./</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>                         <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly-jar-Id</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The setted classpath won´t be dissolved.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Maven archiver documentation](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html) you should use the `<addClasspath>` configuration for this, not try to create the element yourself, e.g.

```
<configuration>
  <archive>
    <manifest>
      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
    </manifest>
  </archive>
  <!--- other configuration here -->
</configuration>
```

Comment: your solution doesn´t work, I got a build error "Cannot find addClasspath in MavenArchiveConfiguration"

Comment: What version of the assembly plugin are you using?  The version is not present in the POM shown.

Comment: oh sorry, I´m using version 2.4

Comment: I missed the `manifest` tags, please try what I have above.  Also, check the docs I linked.